# If I voted to close a question, and the author changes it, can I be notified?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, voting, notifications

Once in while I see a question that was down voted, has a few votes to close, and a comment was left asking for more info such as desired results or pertinent code to be included.

Then the post was edited by the OP with updates and actually has enough to be a good question.

Assuming the question is still open, is there a way for the person(s) who voted the question closed to be notified that an update has taken place?  Specifically, without relying on the post comments.

This would allow user to review it again, retract their close vote and remove down-vote if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Louis, and I like your idea you shared there, "_Now, if the system could tell me when I check my stats and visit the list of questions I've downvoted whether they've been edited since I've downvoted them, this would be a different matter because this feature could be ignored. It would not be invasive like notifications are._"

Comment: Activity to a question does show up in favorites, if you star the question.  Granted, this is a pull rather than push, but you can see things there.

Comment: I think marking a question as a favorite that I wanted to down vote and close defeats the purpose of staring a question... or at least how I like to use favorites :-)  It is a good way to track in the short term, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: This is probably better tagged as _support_ rather than _feature-request_, unless you want to suggest that notifications are received when the edits you're mentioning are made.

Comment: @Tanner, I believe that is the intention, that a user receives a notification when a voted-to-close question is edited.

Comment: Or, As Louis suggested... List the edit activity next to down-voted questions when viewing stats page.  This way you have fewer pointless notifications.

Comment: @PortlandRunner You would be surprised how many people keep track of delete votes via favorites.  +fav something you want to delete in a few days after it gets closed is *quite* common.  There is a [meta.SE feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125180/allow-grouping-of-favorite-questions) for allowing grouping of favorites.  Think of a +fav as more of a 'within SE bookmark' than "OMG! This is the bestest ever!"  As favorites are public, you would also be able to use this later for Data.SE queries and the like for further information gathering.